# Angular 2: update list component from form component sibling

Tags: angular, components, refresh, observable, siblings

I have a parent component, controlling two children.
FormChild is an input form which adds teachers to a list, and edits them, ListChild is a list of the teachers that were input/edited using the FormChild.  The desired behavior (which I've only gotten partially to work) is to have changes in the FormChild reflected in the ListChild.

The FormChild has two modes; edit and add.  A flag determines whether the form has 'add' values or 'edit' values.  When the flag (editing) is true, the 'editTeacher' service method is called, when it is false, the 'addTeacher' service method is called.

```
public emitChangeNotification() {
  this.changeNotifier.emit();
}

teacherAddEdit(event) {

  if (!this.editing) {
    this._userService.addTeacher(this.userItem)
      .subscribe(
        nextItem=> this.nextItemMsg = nextItem
        , error => this.errorMsg = <any> error
        , ()=>this.emitChangeNotification()
      );
  }
  else {
    this._userService.editTeacher(this.userItem)
      .subscribe(
        nextItem=> this.nextItemMsg = nextItem
        , error => this.errorMsg = <any> error
        , ()=>this.emitChangeNotification()
      );
  }
  this.initForm();
}
```

Note that in both add and edit cases, the calls to the service are pretty much the same.  What is supposed to be happening here is that on completion, the observable will call this.EmitChangeNotification, which will bubble up to the parent and then cause the ListChild to update.

The problem is, the ListChild only updates on add, and not on edit!  Tracing through the code with f12, i'm seeing that In the 'add' case, this.EmitChangeNotification gets called; but not in the edit case.  This is only a problem with the web ui; the back end is getting called, and the changes are being persisted in the database just fine.

The service calls in the service are identical except for the specific back-end web api method called:

```
addTeacher(userToCreate:CreateUser)
{
  let Url = this.BASEURL + '/accounts/create';
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = JSON.stringify(userToCreate);
  return this._http.post(this._createUserUrl, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

editTeacher(userToChange:CreateUser)
{
  let Url = this.BASEURL + '/updateTeacher/' + userToChange.UserId;
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = JSON.stringify(userToChange);
  return this._http.post(Url, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Originally, the 'editTeacher' in the service was using  _http.put; i changed this to _http.post; but this didn't help.  I"ve looked at a number of examples; seems like this should just work... what am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

**Edit:** another clue... it seems that the 'on complete' callback of the subscribe is not being called at all in the 'edit' case.  I substituted:

```
, ()=>this.emitChangeNotification()
```

with

```
, ()=>console.log('tell someone')
```

and the log displays the message when adding *but not* when editing.

I can't see how they are different...

Comment: how you come to know that on edit `emitChangeNotification` is not called ? are you receiving any error ?

Comment: I can see it by single stepping through code with f12 on chrome.  Rather than putting changeNotifier.Emit() directly as the third argument to the subscribe, i wrote separate function emitChangeNotification().  I set breakpoint at that function, and it breaks when adding, but not when editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question....

In fact, the web ui was not different.

the difference lay in the web api calls that the angular service was calling. It seems that what has to happen to have the completion call back to fire is that something must be returned from the API.

In the edit case, I was returning nothing, only an HTTP.OK, but when i changed this to return a user object, the call back would fire, and the list updated. It seems to me this would be a good thing to write down somewhere, so I offer it here for posterity in the hopes it will save someone some grief.